# 規約　等に、辿り着きづらい。

Tags: サポート, 機能の要求

今更ですが、

新人では、
マニュアルや、マニュフェスト、
等　資料に、

一見して　辿り着ける、
トップページでは　ないように、
思います。
"

例えば、
"

チャットに　テーマが、
移換したが、

移換先を　見付けるのも、
発言可能条件も、発言方法も、

調べ様すら　解りません。
"

如何でしょう、

新人に　優しくない、
構造では？

Answer (score 6):

スタック・オーバーフローには様々な仕組みがあり、それらを最初からすべて頭に入れてもらうには大変な量になっています。

そこでスタック・オーバーフローではツアーと信用度を利用して徐々に理解していただく方法を取っています。

- ツアー https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour
- 信用度によって得られる権限 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

更に、コミュニティによる編集やコメントなどのモデレーションを通して、必要な部分を必要なだけ知っていく構造もできています。自分で調べて分からなかった場合はメタに Q&A の形で投稿するということもできるようにもなっています。

自分の理解では、そもそもの仕組みが多岐にわたるため、以上のように段階的に仕組みを知れるようになっており、割とこれで運用が回っています。このため、既存の仕組みを変えるのではなく、分からないことがあった度にメタでサイトの使い方について質問いただければな、と思います。その Q&A がナレッジベースを増やし、次の人を助けるでしょう。

Comment: 其方で、
"
質問内に　挙げた、
様々に　辿り着くには、
如何すれば　いいのですか？

Comment: それは別途新しくメタでご質問いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 仮に、
,
ご提案通り　別質問を、
立てれば　即、
類似質問として　此方に、
振り付けられますよね？
"
"
更に、
"
掲げさせて　頂いた、
例えには　一つたりとて、
ご解答では　辿り着けないのでは、
ないでしょうか？
"
"
もしそうなら、
"
申し訳ないが、
等閑としか　いえそうにない
事を　解答とは、
いないと　思うのですが、
"
如何でしょうか？

Comment: チャットについては https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat に記載がありますし、もし https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123667/discussion-on-answer-by-keitaro-so- についてご心配なのであれば https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/123667/discussion-on-answer-by-keitaro-so-?tab=access にあるように権限が自動的に割り振られているので発言可能です。

Comment: 質問が重複とマークされてクローズされるのは、質問のおおよその内容が同じ場合のみです。より具体的に「○○するにはどうすれば良いですか？」という類のメタ質問にしていただければ、それは別のご質問になるでしょう。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: とは　申されましてもね。
"
"
既に、
"
実現したい　事は、
例として　掲げていますよね？
"
"
ですのでね、
"
再投稿しても　要素としては、
大差がない　訳ですよ？
"
"
とはいえ、
"
1度　ご意見を、
伺いましょう。
"
"
例えば、
"
どの様な　文面なら、
此の　質問の、
回答を　得られて。
"
"
尚、
"
此方に　紐付けられなく、
なるのですか？
"
"
後、
"
問われたら毎回、
URLを　一々、
示す　事は、
"
質問趣旨の　「判りづらさ、」の、
裏打ちでは　ないですか？

Comment: 抑もの、
"
貴方の　其の、
反応は、
"
》何処ですか？
に対する　ものですよね？
"
"
しかし、
"
私の　求めは、
軽微な　自助努力のみで、
問わずとも　辿り着ける、
構造では　ないのでは？
"
ですよね？
"
"
いい変えれば、
"
URLを　求めた、
訳ではない　事が、
お判り　頂けますよね？
"
"
詰まり、
"
如何でしょうかね　其方は、
回答たり得ている　ものでしょうかね？

Comment: 書いたとおり、最終的なフォールバック先としてこのメタがあるので、自己言及的に解決している形になっていますね……。

Comment: と　申されますと？

Comment: 自分で調べて分からなければメタに投稿して解決する形になっているので、今回の Q&A 自体がまさにその形になっています。

Comment: では　正に、
今回の　内容、
裏付け　其のものですね。
"
"
今回の、
"
質問内容こそが、
オブラートを　剥がせば、
"
直感的で、ワンストップで、スムーズな、
全域に　ストレスなく、
たとりつける　インターフェイスと、
なっているか？
"
初心者に対して、
特に　優しい、
構造か？
"
ですので。
"
"
質問しなければ　辿り着けない、
事を　受けての、
フォロー体制必要性こそが、
"
私の　疑義点を、
裏付けしている、
"
といえそうでしょうね。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローは Q&A を積み重ねてナレッジベースを作っていくシステムですので、分からなければ質問するというのはこのサイトの根幹になっています。ここは変えにくい部分と思いますし、個人的には特に変えなくて良いとも思います。

Comment: ある程度感じられ方の問題はあるかと思いますが、そこまでいくと各種意見の投票の差を見ていただく他無いかなと感じます。

Comment: いえ、
"
其れは　インターフェース上問題を、
煙に　巻いているだけでは、
ないですか？
"
"
仮に、
"
其れが　正しくば、
全て　質問で、
解決して　いい、
其れこそが　昰ならば、
,
マイナス評価が　限定的てあるべきだ、
FAQ　其の他への、
インターフェースそものもが、
なくてすら　構わない、
"
と　思いませんか？
"
"
しかし、
"
事実としては、
マイナス評価が付いた、
事例が　沢山ありまよね？
"
"
如何でしょうか、
"
事実と、申されるには、
乖離が　あるように、
見受けるのですが。

Comment: 後、
"
其れ等に　従わなければ、
ならない　根拠とは、
何ですか？
"
そうした　契約は、
交わされて　いなかった、
筈では？

Answer (score 6):

少なくともヘルプや規約に関してはトップページ含めた **すべてのページの最下部** (=フッタ) にリンクが設けられており、他の一般的なサイトと大差ないと思います。

また、ヘルプページを開けば検索窓がありますので、まず分からない・調べたい事があればキーワードで **検索** してみてください。

もしヘルプページでも解決しないことがあれば、メタにて (ここでもまずはキーワード検索したうえで) 新規の質問として投稿してもらえれば、回答が付くと思います。

Comment: 当該では、
"
ご提示外アクセスを　かがげていますよね？
"
"
詰まり、
"
おざなりな　質問意図外投稿で、
取りあえず　埋めた、
ものとしか　申せません、
申し訳ないが。