# チャットで　入力欄が、表示されていない。

Tags: バグ, 機能の要求, 仕様

[規約　等に、辿り着きづらい。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3574/%e8%a6%8f%e7%b4%84-%e7%ad%89%e3%81%ab-%e8%be%bf%e3%82%8a%e7%9d%80%e3%81%8d%e3%81%a5%e3%82%89%e3%81%84/3575?noredirect=1#comment3493_3575)
にて、

nekketsuuu様　コメント欄での、
お導きにより、

此方を　拝見しました、
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/123667/discussion-on-answer-by-keitaro-so-?tab=access
"

確かに、

私でも　投稿できる旨、
英表記ながら、
記載が　あります。
"

そこで、

FAQを　参照すると、
》下部に　入力欄がある、
との　事です。
"

しかし、

此の　様に、
[image]
実際に　iPhone画面上では、
入力欄が　見られません。
"

伺います、

此は　対応端境期なのですか？
其れとも　バグですか？
"

今後、

入力できる　方向に、
向かうのですか？

備考、
OS    :iOS14.4
アクセス:ブラウザアクセス
ブラウザ：safari、Firefox、
"

追記、

ご配慮に　感謝を、
致します。

Comment: (元スレッドにおいて) コメント欄での案内が分かりづらかったのかもしれませんが、既に該当のチャット部屋ではあなたも実際に発言しているように見えます。

Comment: 此は　失礼しました、
"
入り方が　判らなかっただけの、
ようですね。
"
ご教示　有り難うございます。
"
"
所で、
"
質問を　閉めるには、
如何すれば　いいのですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちらから入れます。

[image]

下部に入力欄がある、というのは、ここからチャットルームに入った後の説明になります。

Comment: 有り難うございます。